# Problema de wget em python

Tags: python, wget

venho reportar um erro que esta me fazendo bater a cabeça. Eu estou tentando fazer um código para realizar downloads de livros (pdf) de um site do Laos porque é quase impossível baixar todos esses livros manualmente, então tentei fazer o `wget https://lao-online.com/books/download/1.html` só que em python e alterando os links que seguem um padrão, e o código ficou assim

```
import wget
count = 1
print(f'Vamo atrás do {count}° link')

while count < 1800:
    url = (f'https://lao-online.com/books/download/{count}.html')
    print(url)
    sleep(1)
    wget.download(url)
    sleep(1)
    filename = wget.download(url)
    print('Sucesso!')
    count+=1
quit()
```

porém por algum motivo parece que a biblioteca wget do python não deixar eu fazer download de pdf vide visto que eu consegui realizar downloads de outros conteúdos de mídia. Quando eu tento rodar o código o python eu não consigo baixar nada e ele me devolve esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathie/Laos/raspagem.py", line 14, in <module>
    wget.download(url)
  File "/home/mathie/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver é utilizando o requests

```
import requests
import time
import re

header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}

for i in range(3, 10):
    response = requests.get(f'https://lao-online.com/books/download/{i}.html', headers = header)
    response_headers = response.headers['content-disposition']
    file_name = re.findall('filename=(.+)', response_headers)[0]
    file_name = file_name.replace('"','')
    
    with open(f'./{file_name}', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

Importando os pacotes necessários

```
import requests
import time
import re
```

Criando um cabeçalho para o site não recusar a requisição (evitar o erro 403)

```
header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
```

Aqui é onde pegamos o arquivo e salvamos, coloquei de 3 até 10 para teste mas você pode alterar este range

```
for i in range(3, 10):
    response = requests.get(f'https://lao-online.com/books/download/{i}.html', headers = header)
```

Verificando os cabeçalhos do arquivo para obter o nome

```
    response_headers = response.headers['content-disposition']
    file_name = re.findall('filename=(.+)', response_headers)[0]
    file_name = file_name.replace('"','')
```

Salvando o arquivo

```
    with open(f'./{file_name}', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        
    time.sleep(5)
```

Pelo que vi os 2/3 primeiros arquivos não são interessantes, por isso o range começa de 3.

Answer (score 1):

esse erro que você recebe não é do Python ou do wget - é do site de onde está baixando. o código de erro é gerado lá: "403 forbidden". Possivelmente o usuário tenha que estar logado para poder baixa os livros - ai tem que realizar o login usando o Python antes.

(entrei no site - se você olhar a páina de detalhes de cada livro, está de fato, perto do rodapé a instrução "login to download" , cm um link para a página de login)

Nesse caso, se não houver outras restrições de download, a solução vai ser usar a lib "requests" (em vez do 'wget'), e configurar uma "Session", postando as informações de login no endereço adequado - aí, dentro do Python, o objeto "Session" vai ter as mesmas informações que um navegador teria (se forem cookies - alguns sites podem usar cabeçalhos HTTP especializados para informar que estão logados, nesse caso isso também tem que ser escrito no programa).

Aí, usando o método "get" do objeto "session" o download deve funcionar.

Mais tarde talvez eu tenha tempo de criar um exemplo funcionando - (e talvez não)  - por enquanto fica o mapa das pedras aí.

Comment: Então meu caro, bem, digamos que o Laos não possui muita segurança em seu sites para limitar seus downloads e graças a um exploit, quando eu acesso https://lao-online.com/books/download/32.html o site me devolve o pdf requisitado, e como eu citei quando eu uso o wget puro no terminal o wget me baixa o pdf, porém no python isso não acontece, bem, vou tentar alguma coisa o request, valeu pelo caminha do pedras XD